# Adding GCM to project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, terminal, google-cloud-messaging

I want to add GCM to my android project. I have downloaded the config file for GCM. But as per `developers.google.com` I am supposed to run the command

```
$ move path-to-download/google-services.json app/
```

on my Android studio terminal window.

But there is something wrong with my android studio. Every time I open Terminal tab I get this error.

[image]

I know that command is copying something some where. So what is the workaround to that command.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try updating your Android Studio to the latest stable version for a fix issue with the terminal.

You may also copy the `google-services.json` to the folder without using the Android Studio terminal. Open your file manager and paste the file inside the app/ folder of your project.

I also recommend you to try the Firebase Cloud Messaging (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), that is now the official Google product to handle messaging. The GCM will still be supported by Google, but Firebase is the new way to handle this.